# PHP built-in function or library for HTTP POST parameter name format

Tags: php

Hello StackOverflow Community,

**Background:**

JSON data,

```
{
   "trunk":"Thick Oak",
   "leaves":[
      "Funny Leaf",
      "Sad Leaf",
      "Jolly Leaf",
      "Special Leaf"
   ],
   "seeds":[
      {
         "coat":"Brown Coat",
         "endosperm":"Brown Endosperm",
         "embryo":"Brown Embryo"
      },
      {
         "coat":"Yellow Coat",
         "endosperm":"Yellow Endosperm"
      },
      {
         "coat":"Green Coat"
      }
   ]
}
```

PHP code to make a HTTP POST call using above JSON data,

```
function postFormData() {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
    print_r($data);
    $curl = curl_init("http://localhost:8080/post");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

POST parameters name format output in logs,

```
trunk = Thick Oak
leaves[0] = Funny Leaf
leaves[1] = Sad Leaf
leaves[2] = Jolly Leaf
leaves[3] = Special Leaf
seeds[0][coat] = Brown Coat
seeds[0][endosperm] = Brown Endosperm
seeds[0][embryo] = Brown Embryo
seeds[1][coat] = Yellow Coat
seeds[1][endosperm] = Yellow Endosperm
seeds[2][coat] = Green Coat
```

**Question**

Is there any PHP built-in function or library that would convert a PHP array of objects, in this case seeds, to the below HTTP POST parameter name format,

```
seeds[0].coat = Brown Coat
seeds[0].endosperm = Brown Endosperm
seeds[0].embryo = Brown Embryo
seeds[1].coat = Yellow Coat
seeds[1].endosperm = Yellow Endosperm
seeds[2].coat = Green Coat
```

Comment: Why would you want that? It's not the standard format for nested POST parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why would you want to do it, but i array_map should do it.

```
function tobjectArr($a) {
    return (object)$a;
}
$seeds = array_map("tobjectArr", $seeds);
```

Comment: I require the POST parameters names as mentioned above, because the consuming REST services is based on Spring Framework and the naming convention/format for the data binder is as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-beans-conventions). I'm seeking a solution, wherein a class/function would take in a PHP object which may have variables, nested objects, nested arrays, etc... and return a list of name-value pairs to be passed as parameters that adhere to Spring Framework's data binding format. @barmar